# C# visual studio 2015 Access 2013 database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a C# project with Visual Studio 2015 Express where I have an  Access database that I want incorporate into a project, because, I give the   project to a friend, I have to place the Access database into a different folder path, so I want make a folder into project. I don't know the folder's path.

Comment: Sorry I'm not completely sure what you want to do. Do you want to share the access file within the Solution? Lets say as a part of the solution ?

Comment: my  connection string source i like this C:\Users\user\Desktop\es\file.accdb  I want project\folder\fileaccdb

Answer (score 0):

The following sets up a connection for a .accdb database one folder below the application executable. This will not work with a ClickOnce install or if using TableAdapters.

You need to change Databases to a folder that exists and change the database name to match your database,

Hope this helps.

```
// This translates to: AppFolder\Databases\Database1.accdb
// AppFolder: Location of the executable
// DataBases: an existing folder below AppFolder
var databasePathName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"Databases", "Database1.accdb");
var Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
        DataSource = databasePathName
    };
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection() { ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString })
{
    cn.Open();
    // do work
}
```